# MongoDB - PHP - MongoCursorException 'Cursor not found

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Find solutions similar problem - with timeout (-1); and immortal(true); - nothing helped :(

I get this error when this code:

```
$this->start_time = microtime(true);
    $documents = 0;
    $offset = 0; 
    $files = array();

    $mongo = new Mongo();

    $db = Yii::app()->params['mongo']['db'];
    $db->immortal(true);
    $collection = Yii::app()->params['mongo']['collection'];
    $collection_serial = 'new_serial_number';

    $serial_numbers = $mongo->$db->$collection_serial->find();
    $serial_numbers->timeout(-1);

    $update = false;

    foreach ($serial_numbers as $serial_number) {

   //some code here        
    }
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: What driver version and MongoDB version is this? Also can you see the connection in terminal? Basically it means that the server must have cleaned up the cursor but that seems kinda weird especially with the extra code.

Comment: Also, since I cannot edit my old comment now, immortal isn't a good thing to use here, really you should stick to excessive timeout, also I think -1 only works when you are accessing the timeout global var (like `MongoCursor::$timeout = -1`) of the mongodb driver itself otherwise, per the docs, http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php it is actually 0 to give an infinite timeout

Comment: how can i check version?

i'm tried MongoCursor::$timeout = -1, but the result the same

Comment: For the PHP driver look at `phpinfo()`, that's normally the easiest way you can also check with pecl but `phpinfo()` is easiest. For mongoDB you can enter the mongo console and type `db.version()`

Comment: My version of MongoDB is 1.1.3

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen that version in a long long time. What version of the driver? If you have a relatively new driver this could be the cause of the issue

Comment: sorry, it's version of driver
version
mongo: 2.0.6 (64-bit)

Comment: Ah ok, hmm there is nothing odd there, that driver should work ok but to be sure can you upgrade to 1.2 as can be seen from the github https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver ? Also what OS is this?

Comment: it's Win 7. Mongo driver was updated to 1.2.5. all is the same..
I do not even know what's the reason may be.
problem is described in the documentation, and written her solution but it does not work

Comment: http://cpactions.local/3.php

Answer (score 2):

Note:: There is an important distinction between **timeout** and **immortal**!
Timeout indicates the time to wait on the *client* side while immortal sets the cursor on the *server* side.

It is especially useful for large result sets in sharded environments.

--

In which line do you get the exception?

Make sure you use timeout or immortal on the cursor:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->immortal(true); // this
$cursor->timeout(-1); // or this
```

Comment: Now i'm tried to use only 
    "$serial_numbers->timeout(-1);" 
I'm getting the exeption on this line: 
    "foreach ($serial_numbers as $serial_number) {"

Comment: when i use "$cursor->timeout(-1); " - my script will wait forever?